# java -Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0

Tags: java, generics

I am getting this compilation error on running a simple java program in unix from command line :

```
   ERROR in test.java (at line 92)
        List fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                                       ^^^^^^
   Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0
```

This same question [Java - Iterator: "Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985530/java-iterator-syntax-error-parameterized-types-are-only-available-if-source) has answers that generics were introduced in java version > 5.0, but when I do java -version from command line it shows :

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.6)
```

Compliance version is set to 1.4 by default :

```
Compliance options:
-1.3               use 1.3 compliance level (implicit -source 1.3
                   -target 1.1)
-1.4             + use 1.4 compliance level (implicit -source 1.3
                   -target 1.2)
-1.5               use 1.5 compliance level (implicit -source 1.5
                   -target 1.5)
-1.6               use 1.6 compliance level (implicit -source 1.6
                   -target 1.6)
-source <version>  set source level: 1.3 to 1.6 (or 5, 5.0, 6 or 6.0)
-target <version>  set classfile target level: 1.1 to 1.6 (or 5, 5.0, 6 or
                   6.0)
```

How can I change it to 1.5 from command line.

Comment: You've shown the error message but not the command you ran.  How are you invoking the compiler?

Comment: I don't understand; you've got the answer to your own question right in the question: "-1.5               use 1.5 compliance level (implicit -source 1.5 -target 1.5)"

Answer (score 0):

That is the Java Runtime Environment not the development kit.

Check the javac command's version.

Also if you are using an IDE make sure the proper Java version, JDK is being used.